# How to use a non-UI react-native module in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-ios

I am super new to react-native so please go easy on me :)

Say, I need to display a `react-native` screen in my `iOS swift` app, the official way to go is by using `RCTRootView` and we would provide one of it's constructors i.e. `RCTRootView(bridge:moduleName:initialProperties:)` with the specific `module` we want to use.

But what if I need to initialise a `module` that is **non view related**. Say, an auth module or some other data module that has nothing to do with `UI`, In such a case it makes sense that I do not need `RCTRootView` in order to create it since it has zero relation to any `UI`.

I have searched quite a bit in the `react-native` docs trying to search for some tool in the `SDK` that could create a specific `react-native` module without using going the `UI` path and found nothing that can help.

Let me make myself super clear, I know how to create a specific react-native module by using the RCTRootView and that would work 100% in my case, I just think that since it's not a UI component it seems to me as a far fetched option.

I'm just looking for a better alternative.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob to create a native module with Swift.